# Google Transaction Canceled?

Tags: android, transactions, payment-processing, android-pay

I'm using Google's in-app billing V3 to get orders processed in my Android app. I've been testing the system by uploading my APK to beta and listing my email as a test account so that I could go back and forth without being charged anything. These orders all remained (in Google Wallet) as "pending" (i.e., yellow circle). Then, about 1 month after I charged myself, the orders began being automatically canceled by Google. I figured this was because they were all tests.

Recently, I upgraded the APK to published status and got my first real order. Strangely enough, it's still "pending" (no green circle here). This got me to thinking that maybe all the other previous pending orders were actually mistakes. Can anyone confirm this? How do I find out what I did wrong? Or, am I just being a little too rushed and real orders take a long time to process?

The way my system is set up is that as the user pays, I send them the product via email. Does this, in some way, make the transaction not go through? I guess I don't really understand how it all works in the background. Any clarification here would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is for anyone who may run into this problem in the future:

After speaking with a Google representative, the short story is that you just have to wait.

Initially, the same representative informed me that, even with test/beta orders, the transactions would process (just not charged). Because of this, I was under the impression that my code was buggy.

Turns out, beta orders are never processed and remain as "pending" for their entire lifetime (which is a couple of weeks). Real orders, on the other hand, could take 6+ hours to process.

In regards to how the product is delivered, that did not play into the processing equation at all.